# Utilizar XAMMP portable en el disco D

Tags: apache, xampp

Estoy usando la versión potable de XAMMP, y me levanta perfectamente el servidor  (cuando hago las pruebas en mi pc personal  )cuando la carpeta esta ubicada en el disco C:/, lo que si no se puede es abrirlo en el D u otra ruta porque arroja el siguiente error  :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en mi trabajo no tengo permisos para agregar nada a la unidad C , por lo que solo me queda instalarlo en el unidad D , se que probablemente deba cambiar algunas rutas en los documentos de configuración para que funcione en el disco D , como el "ServerRoot" o algo por el estilo. Estoy investigando en la documentación , pero igual quisiera el consejo de alguien que sepa configurar lo como lo requiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno la solucion fue utilizar el archivo setup_xampp , lo cual me configuro algunas variables automáticamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego cambie el puerto 80 a 8080 en la configuracion del httpd.conf (la vieja confiable en XAMPP)

Finalmente reinicie el el servidor apache y listo ! :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Como mismo mencionas debes modificar los fichero httpd.conf, php.ini y httpd-xampp.conf y cambiar las referencias al disco o la carpeta que estes usando. en el boton config tienes acceso a estos 3 ficheros y con un ctrl+R debes poder remplazar facilmente estas referencia al disco actual.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, acabo de encontrar una manera mas rapida de configurarlo , lo publicare como respuesta, creo que hace lo que tu me sugieres pero de forma automatica, es ejecutar un .bat que te configura las variables que mencionas :)

Comment: Perfecto,  realmente es la respuesta saludos :)